# C: read numbers and string from file

Tags: c, file-io, input

I have to read data from a txt file, like this:

- 11 27 12 OY-5158
- 11 28 12 WM-2037
- 12 29 46 PY-6651

The last part has to be in a string, it has 7 character always.

I tried it with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int sorok;
    char s[1000];   //Max number of lines

    FILE *f = fopen("jarmu.txt","r");

    while( (fgets(s, sizeof(s), f)) != NULL) {
      sorok++;
    }

    int idopont[sorok][3];
    char rendszam[sorok][7];

    while (!feof(f))
    {
        for(i=0; i<sorok; i++)
        fscanf(f,"%d %d %d %7s",&idopont[i][0],&idopont[i][1],&idopont[i][2],&rendszam[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<sorok; i++)
    printf("%d %d %d %7s\n",idopont[i][0],idopont[i][1],idopont[i][2],rendszam[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Please define what "doesn't work" mean.

Comment: `char rendszam[sorok][7];` --> `char rendszam[sorok][8];`, `&rendszam[i]` --> `rendszam[i]`, and ,don't use `!eof(f)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simple:

At the moment, you read the file once to get the number of lines, then again to parse those lines. You forgot rewinding in between. Use: `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);`

Also, don't forget to remove your `while(!feof(f))` loop inclusive body.

Alternatively, read the file only once and parse the lines directly.

Next problemspot: C uses 0-terminated strings, and you did not reserve space for the terminating 0. Please correct that too.

Final error: `fscanf(f,"%d %d %d %7s",&idopont[i][0],&idopont[i][1],&idopont[i][2],&rendszam[i]);`
should be `fscanf(f,"%d %d %d %7s",&idopont[i][0],&idopont[i][1],&idopont[i][2],rendszam[i]);`:
The types should be `FILE*, char*, int*, int*, int*, char*`. The last one was `char**`.

Comment: I done this, the program runs, but after it write the data it write some interesting thing.
This is the end of the text written by the exe:
http://i60.tinypic.com/1c7cx.png

Comment: If the &rendszam[i] -> rendszam[i] was that, i already tried it because of the comment of BLUEPIXY but it doesnt help. The program does the same.

Comment: `rendszam[sorok][7+1]`

Comment: Suggest `rewind(f);` rather than `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET)`.

Comment: I finally found it! int sorok -> int sorok=0 :D Thanks to everyone :)